# How to remove the button image of checkbox by java coding?

Tags: android, button, checkbox

I know to remove the button image of checkbox in xml with following code:

```
<CheckBox
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:button="@null"
                android:background="@drawable/notxtcheckboxbtn"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

But I need to add checkbox in my java code. And "newCheckBox.setButtonDrawable(null);" doesn't work!

Anybody know how to remove it in java code? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You could make a transparent 1x1 png and set the background to that from java.

Comment: Thanks Tim. It's a solution. I also want those checkboxes in horizontal layout and without any margin between them. Maybe set leftmargin to -1 can get the result. Thanks again. If no other suggestion. I will use this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the case that you just want the image to be transparent, you could try setting the image to android.R.color.transparent. That should get you the effect you're looking for.

Otherwise if you want to hide the button and disable it, you can use set visibility() and set it to gone or invisible.

Comment: Thanks Lee. I just want the button image be invisible. The text of the checkbox still need be there.

Comment: Oh in that case you could try setting the image to android.R.color.transparent. That should get you the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Of course! I'm going to edit the answer to include that as well

Comment: How do you do it programmatically @JunseokLee?

Comment: Use `setButtonDrawable()

Comment: Do not forget to setPadding to zero, due to the Android version.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
android:button="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: how can we do this programatically